# How to check if today is a weekend in bash?

Tags: perl, bash, scripting

How to check if today is a weekend using bash or even perl?

I want to prevent certain programs to run on a weekend.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
if [[ $(date +%u) -gt 5 ]]; then echo weekend; fi
```

`date +%u` gives you the day of the week from Monday (1) through to Sunday (7). If it's greater than 5 (Saturday is 6 and Sunday is 7), then it's the weekend.

So you could put something like this at the top of your script:

```
if [[ $(date +%u) -gt 5 ]]; then
    echo 'Sorry, you cannot run this program on the weekend.'
    exit
fi
```

Or the more succinct:

```
[[ $(date +%u) -gt 5 ]] && { echo "Weekend, not running"; exit; }
```

To check if it's a *weekday,* use the opposite sense (`< 6` rather than `> 5`):

```
$(date +%u) -lt 6
```

Comment: how about to check if it's weekday? the reverse -- will this work
if [ ![ $(date +%u) -gt 5 ]] ; then
fi

Comment: @Andrei, see the update: I'd just use `-lt 6` instead of `-gt 5`.

Comment: arrgh I mean - -if [[ $(date +%u) -lt 6 ]

Comment: Isn't Sunday 0, Saturday 6??

Comment: @lonewarrior556, no, it's definitely Monday 1 through Sunday 7. I suspect you're thinking about `tm_wday` from the C/C++ `time/ctime` stuff. Try executing `date ; date +%u` and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 15):

```
case "$(date +%a)" in 
  Sat|Sun) echo "weekend";;
esac
```

Comment: Notice that `Sat`/`Sun` is locale dependent.

Answer (score 9):

This is actually a surprisingly difficult problem, because who is to say that "weekend" means Saturday and Sunday... what constitutes "the weekend" can actually vary across cultures (e.g. in Israel, people work on Sunday and have Friday off). While you can get the date with the `date` command, you will need to store some additional data indicating what constitutes the weekend for each locale if you are to implement this in a way that works for all users. If you target only one country, then the solution posed in the other answers will work... but it is always good to keep in mind the assumptions being made here.

Comment: good point. there's also 'long weekends' to consider, for example Bank Holiday Mondays in the UK.

this is why it's helpful for people to give some background to their questions, so people answering know what is and isn't relevant...

Comment: A great point -- In my case, I was referring to Sat and Sunday.

Answer (score 5):

Use Perl's [`localtime`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html) operator.

> #### localtime
>
> Converts a time as returned by the time function to a 9-element list with the time analyzed for the local time zone. Typically used as follows:
>
> ```
> #  0    1    2     3     4    5     6     7     8
> ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime(time);
> ```
>
> …
>
> `$wday` is the day of the week, with 0 indicating Sunday and 3 indicating Wednesday.

For example:

```
$ date
Sun Aug 15 20:27:29 CDT 2010

$ perl -le 'my $wday = (localtime)[6];
            print $wday >= 1 && $wday <= 5 ? "weekday" : "weekend"'
weekend
```

Answer (score 2):

printf also has date

```
printf -v day '%(%a)T'
case $day in 
    Sat|Sun) echo "Hooray!";;
esac
```

https://ideone.com/wU7C0c - demo

Answer (score 1):

I like this way of running programs on weekdays:

```
[[ $(date +%u) -lt 6 ]] && weekday-program
```

It is a bit tricky construction, but compact and easy to add.

Comment: Cron has it's own syntax to run comands on weekdays `* * * * 1-5 user echo ok`

Comment: You are right. The native cron way is preferred in most cases. However, the trick I suggested still applicable in cron. For example, if you schedule a script with a set of actions that should be performed one by one in a defined order, but some actions should be skipped in some conditions.

Comment: In case of some complicated logic I'll rather put it script than in crontab.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure if this is suited to this question but I wanted to share this it to help others out and this is the closest Stack question to what I was looking for.

This is a shell script that I use for starting an application when i boot my computer, the application cannot connect to its server over the weekend (its down for maintenance as the service doesn't run at weekends (forex trading application).

Information about this script, d is 1 to 7 (mon to sun) h is 24 time. You can adjust this to your own settings, maybe you have a midweek maintenance or any other cause. This is my first ever shell script, so I'm sure there is a better way and if anybody wants make edits, feel free I will review for acceptance (or somebody else may do it)

```
#!/bin/bash
d=$(date +%u)
h=$(date +%H)
case $d in
    '5')
    # Friday after 10pm
    if (($h >= 22)) ; then  
        exit
    fi
    ;;
    '6')
    # all day saturday
        exit
    ;;
    '7')
    #sunday before 10pm
    if (($h < 22)) ; then  
        exit
    fi
    ;;
    *)
    # any other time run the program

    ;;
esac
```