# program to check if today is sunday

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

This program is about  to check if today is sunday or not i am considering the output of this as string `"$(date|cut -d ' ' -f 1)"` and then i am comparing the two strings

```
#!/bin/bash
    datetoday="$(date|cut -d ' ' -f 1)"
echo "${datetoday}"
s2="Sun"
if [ "${datetoday}" == "$s2" ]
then
echo "weekend"
else
echo "not weekend"
fi
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: this program is not giving output

Comment: Rather than `date | cut ...` try `date +%a`

Comment: It's giving me the output "Wed␊not weekend" when I run it.  How are you running the script?

Comment: This might help: `[[ $(date +"%u") -eq 3 ]] && echo "Wednesday"` and `man date`

Comment: can we do this using `date | cut`

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This question already has an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490032/how-to-check-if-today-is-a-weekend-in-bash

Comment: i want to do that using `date | cut`

Comment: Although there's no reason to use `date | cut` over `date +%a`, there's also nothing obvious wrong with what you posted.

Comment: You may want to set the locale so that your comparisons work independent of languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`date` can output the day you are on, with `%a` (Sun) and `%A` (Sunday).
Both of them will suffice:

```
#!/bin/bash
today="$(date +%a)"
sun="Sun"
[ "${today}" = "${sun}" ] && printf "weekend\n" || printf "not weekend\n"
exit 0
```

You can easily use `%A` setting `sun` as `Sunday` instead of `Sun` (`sun="Sunday"`)

If you need to check all the days, you can swap the test with a case statement, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
today="$(date +%a)"
case "${today}" in
  Mon|Monday)
    printf "not weekend\n"
    ;;
  ### etc.
  Sun|Sunday)
    printf "weekend\n"
    ;;
esac
exit 0
```

EDIT: As @tinita said, if you don't set a proper locale, you may not match the day with "Sunday" (E.G. In French would be "Dimanche" and in Italian would be "Domenica").

You can avoid this changing locale, or using another option of `date`.

In fact, `date +%u` will give you a number from 1 to 7 where 1 is Monday.

```
#!/bin/bash
today="$(date +%a)"
[ "${today}" -eq 7 ] && printf "weekend\n" || printf "not weekend\n"
exit 0
```

Another thing @chepner noted is that if you are writing the output on a file and you don't have enough space in your file system to write "weekend\n" (8 bytes), the shortcut `a && b || c` will not work.

Sideswipes aside, it is true indeed that the shortcut is not a proper way to make an `if` statement and you should always prefer the canonical way:

```
#!/bin/bash
today="$(date +%a)"
if [ "${today}" -eq 7 ]; then
  printf "weekend\n"
else
  printf "not weekend\n"
fi
exit 0
```

Comment: Don't use `a && b || c` as a shortcut for a proper `if` statement. The two are not equivalent if there is a chance that `b` could fail.

Comment: Note that this not portable without setting locale

Comment: @chepner You are right, and because of printing a static string with `printf` cannot fail, this is equivalent to an `if` statement
@tinita You are right, I just "hardcoded" english days because the question was stated with `Sun`

Comment: `printf` *can* fail, even with a hard-coded string. One example is a script whose caller redirects standard output to a file on a full file system. There's simply no reason to replace the perfectly correct usage of an `if` statement with this hack.